# Value not getting assigned to double variable

Tags: android, android-edittext, double

I am trying to assign a value fetched from my EditText to a double variable.

I have done something like this:-

```
    public class PersonalInfo extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
    {
        private double height=0.0d, weight=0.0d;
    private CheckBox cbCheck;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal_info);
        try
               {
                   height = Double.parseDouble(etHeight.getText().toString().trim());
                   weight = Double.parseDouble(etWeight.getText().toString().trim());

               }
               catch(NumberFormatException e)
               {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

     cbCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                //is chkIos checked?
                        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                            Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this,height+weight), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                      }
                    });
}
    }
    }
```

When I debug the program, I get the value of `Double.parseDouble(etHeight.getText().toString().trim());`  perfectly. But somehow when I check the value of height and weight they remain null.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: what is the scope of the variable height. Where is it declared? and where do you use the variable height?

Comment: Where do you have this `height = Double.parseDouble(etHeight.getText().toString().trim());` are you sure you get the value right?

Comment: @Raghunandan its within onCreate()

Comment: Move that to onClick method the try catch block

Comment: see the reason why it happens in the below post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting text from editText early in `onCreate`. User interaction starts when activity resumes in `onResume`. So you need to get text from `EditText` when user has entered some value. Also you could do some checks

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(etHeight.getText().toString())
{
    // do something
}
```

So move the try catch block inside `public void onClick(View v) {`

Comment: sir i  deleted my answer may be your answer full fill the requirement of the questionare